# i need MACD data of 15 min timeframe on my 5 Min time frame chart to use it in a strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need MACD data of a 15-minute timeframe ( histogram) on my 5-minute time frame chart to use it in a strategy.

```
request.security_lower_tf(symbol, timeframe, expression, ignore_invalid_symbol, currency, ignore_invalid_timeframe) → array<type>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get MACD data for a 15 minute time period (histogram) on your 5 minute time period chart using the `f_security` function from [this library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/00jFIl5w-security-revisited-PineCoders/)

Something like this:

```
f_security(_symbol, _res, _src, _repaint) =>
  request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])
                                      [_repaint ? 0 : barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

hist         = f_security(syminfo.tickerid, '15',
               ta.ema(close, 12) - ta.ema(close, 26) -
               ta.ema(ta.ema(close, 12) - ta.ema(close, 26), 9),
               true)

plot(
  hist,
  title      = "Histogram",
  style      = plot.style_columns,
  color      = (hist >= 0 ?
                  (hist[1] < hist ? #26A69A : #B2DFDB) :
                  (hist[1] < hist ? #FFCDD2 : #FF5252)))
```